# Using datetime package to convert a date with time to only date.

Tags: python, datetime, dictionary

My function is to read data from a file that consists of dates with times a tweet was written, and sentiments (good, bad or neutral) it's classified as; select date with times, and sentiments between a start and end date; and finally create three dictionaries (positive, negative and neutral) that use the date as key, and number of positive, negative or neutral tweets made in a day.

The problems I have are:

a) How do I get only date to display, and not date and time?.

b) How do I get my program to include both start and end date?

c) How do I separate a key and value with a semi-colon in a dictionary?

```
def get_sentiment_dates(start_date, end_date):
    positive_dict = {}
    negative_dict = {}
    neutral_dict = {}
    f = open("BAC2_answer.csv", "r")
    tweets = f.readlines()
    bin_use =[]
    bin_trash =[]
    bin_use_senti = []
    bin_trash_senti = []
    start_date_obj = datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
    end_date_obj = datetime.strptime(end_date, '%Y-%m-%d')
    for i in tweets:
        specs = i.split(',')
        t_and_d = specs[0]
        dt_obj = datetime.strptime(t_and_d, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        chars_body = specs[1].strip()
        if ((dt_obj >= start_date_obj) and dt_obj <= (end_date_obj)):
            bin_use.append(dt_obj)
            bin_use_senti.append(chars_body)
        else:
            bin_trash.append(dt_obj)
            bin_trash_senti.append(chars_body)
    num_of_pos = 0
    num_of_neg = 0
    num_of_neut = 0
    for i,j in zip(bin_use, bin_use_senti):
        if j == 'Bullish':
            num_of_pos +=1
            positive_dict = (i, num_of_pos)
        elif j == 'Bearish':
            num_of_neg+=1
            negative_dict = (i, num_of_neg)
        else:
            num_of_neut+=1
            neutral_dict = (i, num_of_neut)
    # print str(positive_dict) + "," + str(negative_dict) + "," + str(neutral_dict)
    f.close()
    return [positive_dict,negative_dict,neutral_dict]
```

Comment: I admit that I didn't read your post/code all that carefully since I don't have much time at the moment, but you might be able to use the `.date()` method of `datetime` objects

Comment: For (a), I could use .date(), and for (b), I think I could use timedelta. I learned that a little later. Your post is certainly helpful! Any idea as to how to get a dictionary in k:v format? Mine uses a comma as a separator now...

Comment: @squidvision It's not entirely clear to me what is being asked here. If you provide a sample input and a sample output, it will be much easier for people to help you with what you want to do.